# getting WA in uva 10954

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

lets add some  flavor of ingenuity to it.Addition operation requires cost now, and the cost is the summation of those two to be added. So,to add 1 and 10, you need a cost of 11. If you want to add 1, 2 and 3. There are several ways1 + 2 = 3, cost = 31 + 3 = 4, cost = 42 + 3 = 5, cost = 53 + 3 = 6, cost = 62 + 4 = 6, cost = 61 + 5 = 6, cost = 6Total = 9Total = 10Total = 11I hope you have understood already your mission, to add a set of integers so that the cost is minimal.Input Each test case will start with a positive number,N(2N5000) followed by N positive integers(all are less than 100000). Input is terminated by a case where the value of N is zero. This case should not be processed.Output For each case print the minimum total cost of addition in a single line.

Sample Input

```
3   
1 2 3   
4  
1 2 3 4  
0
```

Sample Output

```
9  
19
```

i tried to sort the given array and then took another array for cumsum (CS) and summed all element of CS except cs[0].. i am getting WA for this approach, please explain

```
int n,i,hold=0;   

while(1)   
{
    cin>>n;

    if(n==0){break;}

    int arr[n],cs[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>arr[i];

    sort(arr,arr+i);

    cs[0]=arr[0];

    for(i=1;i<n;i++){cs[i]=arr[i]+cs[i-1]; }

    cs[0]=0;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){sum+=cs[i]; }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    sum=0;

}
```

input:

```
9
66 85 52 22 44 1 59 88 67 
0
```

my out:

```
1822
```

expected result(udebug):

```
1454
```

getting WA

Comment: `int arr[n],cs[n];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: You have a test input that fails. This puts you miles and miles ahead of most folk who ask one of these questions. What you should do is fire up the debugging tool that came with your development environment, feed in your input case, and step through the program until you spot where the program deviates from your expectations. This is usually a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is wrong to solve this problem.
after taking all the elements on a data structure you should **repeat this 3 points**:
***1)sort.
2)sum 1st two value,and remove 1st two value from the data structure 
3)add the sum to the cost and data structure.***
you can use **priority_queue** as the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use min heap and add 2 smallest element. Example:

1 2 3 -> 3 3 -> 6.
1 2 3 4 -> 3 3 4 -> 4 6 -> 10.

Hope it helps.